# requirejs opentok script error for: OT

Tags: requirejs, opentok

I'm trying to load opentokjs from cdn using requirejs as described here: https://forums.tokbox.com/javascript/loading-javascript-using-requirejs-t42411.

In my main.js i have

```
shim:{
    'ng-tok': {
        'exports': 'ng-tok',
        'deps': ['OT', 'angular']
    },
    'tbjs': {
        'exports': 'OT'
    }
}

paths:{
    'tbjs' : ['//static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/opentok.min'],
}
```

But I'm getting Script error for: OT

How do I properly load opentokjs via requirejs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use 'tbjs' rather than 'OT' in the 'deps' of 'ng-tok'.

```js
shim:{
    'ng-tok': {
        'exports': 'ng-tok',
        'deps': ['tbjs', 'angular']
    },
    'tbjs': {
        'exports': 'OT'
    }
}

paths:{
    'tbjs' : ['//static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2/js/opentok.min'],
}
```

Change the version v2.2 to v2 to get the latest version. Thank @Ankur for his comment and sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: You should also link to the latest version of the OpenTok JS SDK. Change the path value to `'https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min'`

Comment: @Ankur It is ok not changing the path. It will add the protocol when running in the browser. I have tried myself and `opentok.min` is loaded successful without changing the path.

Comment: @JasmineOT: Ankur means change `/v2.2/` in your path to `/v2/`. When you use `/v2.2/` in the path it will always point to version 2.2. Pointing to `/v2/` will get the latest 2 version, meaning 2.x

Comment: @MarkVeenstra Thanks for your comment. I was thinking Ankur asked me to add 'https'. I will change my answer and accept Ankur's comment.

Comment: @JasmineOT I totally agree that it would work without explicitly using `https`, but its now considered a bad practice to load assets without the protocol. See http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/